# Send a file to a specific user from the admin page in django

Tags: django

I am on a django project where I want to be sending different work to each of my employees from the admin page, but no one will see other people's work, each person will see their own work in their profile page...
Can anyone please assist me on what I should do...

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the get_queryset in  work modelAdmin and filter objects with any request user till see user your works.

Also You can read django permission doc for another way handling this issue